# Azure CLI(Export azure resource to csv)

Tags: azure, azure-functions, command-line-interface

How to export the azure resources to csv file, using azure CLI?

I’m new to azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get list of resources you can use:

`az resource list`

you can add `--out` switch and use the following formats: json, jsonc, yaml, yamlc, table, tsv but not CSV.

In bash you can try something like this to convert `tsv` to `csv`:

`az resource list --out tsv | sed 's/\t/,/g'`

or with PowerShell as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/680382/exporting-results-from-azure-cli-to-my-environment.html).

Answer (score 0):

***You can use the below comdlet in azure powershell:***

***This is an aternative workaround from powershell to export resources in csv file :***

```
Get-AzResource | Export-Csv -Path "C:\NewFolder\test.csv"
```

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

***References taken from:***

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresource?view=azps-8.1.0
- https://dailydotnettips.com/export-the-list-of-azure-resources-to-excel/